# Get the numbers which occurs maximum time sql

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a scenario where I have to get the number which occurs maximum time per company code. The problem is that when there are two or three numbers which occurs same number of times I have to take the average.

```
Company Code   Value
-----------------------
AA               2
AA               2
AA               3
BB               5
BB               5
BB               7
BB               7
BB               9
```

In the above scenario the output should be

- AA 2 - Since 2 occurs twice while 3 occurs only once.
- BB 6 - Since for BB both 5 & 7 occurs 2 so I have to take the average.

Thanks in advance

Comment: **A tip**. You can take average in every case, as average of just one element will be the value of the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the below query, the following computations are done before getting the final output.

(i) Get the count at this partition level (Company_Code,Value) and assign a rank in descending order.

(ii) Once the rank is assigned select all the rows with rank=1 and average for each Company_Code.

```
SELECT Company_Code,
       AVG(Value) 
  FROM
     (  
       SELECT Company_Code,
              Value,
              RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY 
                            Company_Code,Cnt_Company_Code_Value
                            ORDER BY Cnt_Company_Code_Value DESC 
                          )  
           AS Rank_Company_Code_Value 
      FROM     
        (
           SELECT Company_Code, 
                  Value,
                  COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY Company_Code,Value ) 
                  AS Cnt_Company_Code_Value 
             FROM Table
        )
    )
WHERE Rank_Company_Code_Value = 1
GROUP BY Company_Code;
```